# Errors in outputing elements in a List<int>

Tags: c#, list

I'm coding a program to find perfect numbers. I have found some interesting properties and worked on my code to generate perfect numbers. This is my idea:

```
{
    List<int> nums = new List<int>();
    for (int i = 2; i < upperbound; i++)
    {
        if (IsPrime(i))
        {
            int mersenneNumber = (int)Math.Pow(2, i) - 1;
            if (IsPrime(mersenneNumber))
            {
                int perfectNumber = (int)Math.Pow(2, i - 1) * mersenneNumber;
                nums.Add(perfectNumber);
            }
        }
    }
    return nums;
}
static bool IsPrime(int number)
{
    if (number <= 1)
        return false;

    for (int i = 2; i <= Math.Sqrt(number); i++)
    {
        if (number % i == 0)
            return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

[image: Debug Console Image]
The output is correct for the first 4 perfect numbers, however I don't know why it failed on the 5th and outputted negative numbers (with `foreach (int j in TesterPerfectNumber(20)){Console.WriteLine(j);}`):

I suspect the bug is in my algorithm, but the alternative form of finding perfect numbers is (2^(p-1))*(2^p - 1) with p and 2^p-1 being primes. Also, I have already found another way to find perfect numbers but consumes more storage and time, basically looping and finding factors of all positive numbers and adding up until it reaches the upperbound limit.

Can you help me debug the code or come up with another reasonable solution to my code? Or are there any limits to the `List<T>` or `int` that I haven't taken into consideration? Please help me and thanks.

Comment: Please post a [mre].  (Definition for `upperbound`, and `IsPrime()` are missing)

Comment: You just have an overflow of the `int` datatype. The biggest number an `int` can hold is `2.147.483.647` the 5th perfect number you are trying to generate is `8.589.869.056`, ie four times `int.MAX_VALUE`.

Comment: but why does it keep generating instead of stopping at 33 million?

Comment: Why should it stop? I don't see any condition for that.

Comment: What is `TesterPerfectNumber`?

Comment: there is a better method that i used

Comment: BTW Have a look at the table in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Mersenne_primes_and_perfect_numbers and see  why your approach doing this with primitive datatypes like `int` or `double` is doomed to failure. Furthermore searching for somewhat bigger Mersenne primes (ie  after the 10th or 11th) also isn't really feasable on a single computer, because it will take too long (especially using the simple, but naive primality test). There is a huge distributed computing network  dedicated to this type of calculations, but still no new one was found for the last 5 years

Comment: Furthermore, your primality test is doing twice the work it needs to do. Because the only even number you have to check with `number % i == 0` is `i == 2`. Because if a number isn't divisible by `2` it won`t be divisible by any other even number either ...

Comment: In fact to make this remotely efficent you should probalby keep a list of already found primes and do your modulo test only using this primes. And there is a very specialized (and much faster) method for testing whether a mersenne number (ie `2^p - 1`) is a prime.

Answer (score -1):

I think that you have to change type to another, because of range of int values from -2147483648 to 2147483647, so thats why when you reached high point it start to be negative.

You can try to use decimal type, because it has more wide range, but in this case you should stop using Math.pow and change it to manual implementation of Pow method to avoid cast error to "double"

Comment: I also thought of that, but there is no `List<long>`, I'd like to use a list because it is practical for other programming languages.

Comment: @OscarNguyen Why do you think there is no `List<long>`? But even that will you bring only three steps further, because the 9th perfect number then exceeds the range of a `long` (9.223.372.036.854.775.807)

Answer (score -1):

There is a `List<long>()`, and you should use it when you need/want to store numbers that are this big.

Also use `Convert.ToInt64()` to convert the Double to a long.

```
        List<long> so77811759()
        {
            List<long> nums = new List<long>();
            for (int i = 2; i < upperbound; i++)
            {
                if (IsPrime(i))
                {
                    int mersenneNumber = (int)Math.Pow(2, i) - 1;
                    if (IsPrime(mersenneNumber))
                    {
                        Double d = Math.Pow(2, i - 1) * mersenneNumber;
                        if (d>long.MaxValue) {
                            Console.WriteLine("value too large for a Double!");
                            break;
                        }
                        nums.Add(Convert.ToInt64(d));
                    }
                }
            }
            return nums;
        }
```

EDIT: So the approach is incorrect for finding what he want to find.

you need another type like `BigInteger` to do this:

```
        List<BigInteger> so77811759()
        {
            List<BigInteger> nums = new List<BigInteger>();
            for (int i = 2; i < upperbound; i++)
            {
                if (IsPrime(i))
                {
                    int mersenneNumber = (int)Math.Pow(2, i) - 1;
                    if (IsPrime(mersenneNumber))
                    {
                        BigInteger d = (BigInteger)Math.Pow(2, i - 1) * mersenneNumber;
                        nums.Add(d);
                    }
                }
            }
            return nums;
        }
```

This way the 75th number will be: `346583711603711240066869986164390514679366392276370459844483478024911453691912726503944226098664612682165286905431498230325051392`

Comment: this will bring him only 3 steps further, because the 9th perfect number exceeds the range of `long`

Comment: indeed.    So the approach is incorrect for finding what he want to find.

Comment: And at a certain range, also the precision of `double` won't be enough anymore, to hold the exact result of `Math.pow(2, i)` Because eventhough the range of a `double` is about up to 10^308, it only has 15 - 17 significant digits

Comment: The approach is perfectly valid, but the standard integral and floating point types are typically not suited for this sort of calculations, but you have to use types like `BigInteger`, which are designed to hold arbitrary large numbers (but come with the price of significantly lower performance and maybe not having implemented all necessary arithmetic operations for a certain usecase)

Comment: I highly doubt that your value for the 75th number is correct. Especially because there are currently only 51 Mersenne primes known , and the perfect number created with that last Mersenne Prime (`2^82,589,933 - 1`) has about 50 million digits ... :-)

Comment: Ok, then the method used here is incorrect.  And I could have noticed that when I was more into mathematics.  When it needs to me a prime, it cannot be an even number (ending in `2`)., and the question has a list with only **even** values....  
  conclusion: `IsPrime()` is incorrect.

Comment: WAIT!:  There is a difference between _mersenne numbers_ and _perfect numbers_, see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Mersenne_primes_and_perfect_numbers

Comment: The method per se and also the `IsPrime()` are perfectly valid (letting aside the used numeric types cannot hold the range of the numbers generated). But your code uses `(int)Math.Pow(2, i) - 1;` which just wrong because it again limits the mersene number to the range of integer ...

Comment: A *Mersenne Prime* is a prime number which can be expressed as `(2^p) -1`. It can be shown, that if `2^p - 1` is prime, then also `p` must be prime, but not for every prime `p` also `2^p -1` is prime. And a "Perfect number*  is a number `((2^p) -1) * 2^(p-1))`, where `2^p -1` is a Mersenne Prime. And if you multiply an odd number (ie the Mersenne prime) with an even number (ie 2^anything), of course you get an even number ...

Comment: the 75th number shared above, is not a `mersenne number`, and might nog even be a `perfect number`.  It's just the 75th value returned from this source.

Comment: That's why I said, I doubt that value is the 75th perfect number ... And again, the algorithm per se is fine. Just the used types are not capable of holding the results and intermediate results ... If you want to do this beyond the first about 10 perfect numbers, you must not use any other type than `BigInt` also for calculating the respective power of 2 ...

Comment: I know that perfect numbers are big, but I really need to minimize the amount of time taken to do the calculation. Also, I used the way of `List <T>` because I also need to translate it into another low level language (like scratch). Using the looping through every `k < upperbound` algorithm takes too long to run on my computer (for the value of 1 000 000 000). My goal here is to minimize the time and storage, not really how far can I go. I can go with `List <long>()` in my code, and maybe `List <BigInteger>()`. I  expect to see the 6th number appearing in my console soon...

Comment: @derpirscher True, perfect numbers _only_ end with 6 or 8. Also, do you guys have Discord?

Comment: Also, the BigInteger method failed as the `IsPrime()` cannot take the `Math.Sqrt()` method of a `BigInteger` type.